# Freeform 3.x and an array causing blank lines in email template

Tags: email, solspace-freeform

I'm using freeform 3.x and I have a series of input fields that are like such:

```
<input type="text" name="order[]" title="Unique Title 1" />
<input type="text" name="order[]" title="Unique Title 2" />
<input type="text" name="order[]" title="Unique Title 3" />
<input type="text" name="order[]" title="Unique Title 4" />
<input type="text" name="order[]" title="Unique Title 5" />
```

Essentially, this is a long list which is published by a channel, thus why I'm using "order[]" and not creating individual form names in Freeform. I have a bit of jQuery that will grab the title and append it to the value which gives me more information in my email notification along with user input.

However, for every input field that I'm using the email template notification via freeform puts a space in there. Not every input field is filled out. I have a long list. So my email notification looks something like below, which is no good as my list will be hundreds of items, meaning hundreds of empty spaces. Can freeform be modded somehow to ignore line-breaks or anything to prevent this from happening?

```
Salmon 1 Available - 56


Gummi Fish preorder - 55











shrimp preorder - 65
```